# How to make routes like this api/users/${userID}/${userDbID} using nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

If I am making an api for fetching user posts data and i want to have a route like
api/users/${userID}/${userDbID}
How can I make these kind of routes using NUXT?

Comment: Put them in a file like `/server/api/users/[userID]/[userDbID].js|ts`. https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/server/

Comment: @some-user will I be able access both the user id & user database id in [userDbID] file ? & how should i access that from params in that file?

Comment: Did you take a look at the linked documentation?

Comment: @some-user Yes. I was just reading it and found the topic for handling requests with query parameters and it works as I wanted. Thank you for helping. 
Doc link -https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/server/#handling-requests-with-query-parameters

Comment: @some-user Can you please post your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server routes can be created by placing files in `~/server/`. Route parameters can be defined by using filenames like this:

```
~/server/api/users/[userID]/[userDbID].js|ts
```

See: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/server/#matching-route-parameters

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from the asked question that you understand the following topics

1- NUXT Application repository structure to represent its components and service interfaces

2- Point 1 will give the pointer how will you control the application routes to serve components views, application pages, layout and other required resources.

hint: Nuxt auto-creates the application route against each .vue file that exists in Pages folder.

You might want to manage the states of Application component data which you referred as 'User'- Please explore a bit further how states declaration & its management works in NUXT defined application, and how would you map services routes with the expected functionality for the application. This will evolve your application to apply action, mutations etc with the context of the User user/:userid/...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).